# Completely stumped on a multiple loop Java program

Tags: java

The following is NOT a homework problem, it's just a set of problems that I've been working through for practice and I was wondering if anybody else could figure it out:

http://codingbat.com/prob/p159339

Return an array that contains exactly the same numbers as the given array, but rearranged so that every 3 is immediately followed by a 4. Do not move the 3's, but every other number may move. The array contains the same number of 3's and 4's, every 3 has a number after it that is not a 3 or 4, and a 3 appears in the array before any 4.

*SOLVED - here is my working code:

```
    public int[] fix34(int...nums) 
{
    int[] returnArray = new int[nums.length];

    //ASSIGN ARRAY
    //We know that all 3's can't be moved, and after every 3 there
    //will automatically be a 4

    for(int i = 0; i<nums.length; i++)
    {
        if(nums[i] == 3)
        {
           returnArray[i] = 3;
           returnArray[i+1] = 4;
        }
    }

    //REBUILD ARRAY - UNMOVED INDEXES
    //If a value was not moved/affected by the above, it will get placed into the array
    //in the same position

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        if (returnArray[i] != 3 && returnArray[i] != 4 && nums[i] != 3 && nums[i] != 4)
        {
            returnArray[i] = nums[i];
        }
    }       

    //REBUILD ARRAY - MOVED INDEXES
    //changed values = 0 in returnArray, as a result, any time we hit a 0 we
    //can simply assign the value that was in the 4's place in the nums array

    OuterLoop: for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        if (returnArray[i] == 0)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < returnArray.length; n++)
            {
                if (returnArray[n] == 4)
                {
                    returnArray[i] = nums[n];
                    continue OuterLoop;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return returnArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know java, but maybe I can help anyway. i dont want to give you the solution, but think of it like this:

you can move every number that isn't a 3. that's our only limit. that being said:

the only spots you need to change are the spots following 3s....so....every time you loop through, your program should be aware if it finds a spot after a 3 that isn't a 4....

it should also be aware if it finds any 4s not preceded by a 3......

during each loop, once it's found the location of each of those two things, you should know what to do.

Comment: Another important piece is that the problem spec also indicates that every input is "solveable". Ie. there won't be any cases where there _isn't_ a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize all the variables

```
    for(int i = 0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == 3)
        {
            if(arr[i+1] == 4)
                continue;
            else
            {
                temp = 0;
                while(arr[temp] != 4)
                    temp++;
                //Write your own code here
            }
         //Complete the code
    }
```

I have `NOT` provided the entire code. Try completing it as you said it was for your practice.

Comment: there is a small problem when the first 3 appears after the last 4 I don't know if that was intentional or not but it would require looping over the entire array not just the remainder of the array.

Comment: I was just able to get to this today after class! I tried a different method, it should account for the 4's being in front of the 3's. Like I said, I'm still new to this, so anything you could optimize or recommend as far as "best practices" would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] fix34(int[] nums) {
    int[] arr = new int[nums.length];
            int index = 0;
            int tempVal= 0,j=0;

            for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
                if(nums[i]==3){
                    arr[i] = nums[i];
                    index=i+1;
                    tempVal = nums[i+1];
                    j=index;

                    while(j<nums.length){
                        if(j<nums.length && nums[j]==4){


                            //System.out.println(j+"\t="+nums[j]);
                            nums[j]=tempVal;
                            nums[index] = 4;
                            break;

                        }
                        j++;

                    }
                    tempVal=0;
                    index=0;
                    }else{
                    arr[i] = nums[i];
                }


            }

            index =0;


            for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
                if(nums[i]==3 && nums[i+1]==4){
                    i+=1;
                }else if(nums[i]==4){
                    index = i;
                    j=index;

                    while(j<nums.length){
                        if(nums[j]==3 && nums[j+1]!=4){

                            arr[index] = nums[j+1];
                            arr[j+1] = 4;

                        }

                        j++;
                    }

                }
            }

            return arr;
    }
```

Comment: this is my solution to the problem

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." Do not provide only the code, but also some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine: A little overkill, but is always right, anyways i make 2 additional arrays and I make 2 passes in the loop putting the correct elements in the correct places. See Logic Below.

```
public int[] fix34(int[] nums) {
  int index1 = 0;
  int index2 = 0;
  int index3 = 0;
  int[] only4 = fours(nums); //holds all 4's in nums
  int[] misc = new int[count4(nums)]; //will hold numbers after 3
  for(int a = 0; a < nums.length - 1; a++){
  if(nums[a] == 3){
  misc[index1] = nums[a + 1]; //get it for later use
  index1++;
  nums[a + 1] = only4[index2]; //now the number after 3 is a 4, from the 
  index2++;                    //only4 array
  }
  }
  for(int b = 1; b < nums.length; b++){
  if(nums[b] == 4  && nums[b - 1] != 3){ //finds misplaced 4's
  nums[b] = misc[index3]; //replaces lone 4's with the
  index3++; //right hand side of each 3 original values.
  }
  }
  return nums;
}
public int count4(int[] nums){
  int cnt = 0;
  for(int e : nums){
  if(e == 4){
  cnt++;
  }
  } 
  return cnt;
}
public int[] fours(int[] nums){
  int index = 0;
  int[] onlyFours = new int[count4(nums)]; //must set length
  for(int e : nums){
  if(e == 4){
  onlyFours[index] = e;
  index++;
  }
  }
  return onlyFours;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine using two ArrayLists which contain the places of 3's and 4's.
I hope this helps.

```
public int[] fix34(int[] nums) 
{
      //Create a copy of nums to manipulate.
      int[] ret = nums;
      //Create two ArrayLists which carry corresponding places of 3 and 4;
      ArrayList<Integer> threePositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      ArrayList<Integer> fourPositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      //Get the places of 3 and 4 and put them in the respective ArrayLists.
      for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
      {
        if (ret[i] == 3)
        {
          threePositions.add(i);
        }
        if (ret[i] == 4)
        {
          fourPositions.add(i);
        }
      }
      //Swap all ints right after the 3 with one of the 4s by using the referenced
      //ArrayLists values.
      for (int i = 0; i < threePositions.size(); i++)
      {
        int temp = ret[threePositions.get(i) + 1];
        ret[threePositions.get(i) + 1] = ret[fourPositions.get(i)];
        ret[fourPositions.get(i)] = temp;
      }
      //Return the ret array.
      return ret;
    }
```

Comment: How's that for easy?

Comment: I could use arrays, but I think it's better and more versatile to use  ArrayLists.